# custom malloc implementation using a char array as the memory

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, free

I'm really bad in C programming. I'm asked to do the following task
Implement a malloc like memory allocation library.

1. Declare an array of 20000 bytes.
2. You must implement a function that is like malloc(). Call it MyMalloc(). Its signature is similar to malloc(). You should also implement MyFree() which has a signature and functionality that are similar to free().
3. MyMalloc() allocates memory only from the previously mentioned array of 20000 bytes.
4. All the data structures that are required to manage the memory must also reside within the same array.
5. MyMalloc() and MyFree() must be in a file called mymalloc.c. You should also provide a suitable header file mymalloc.h.

Can someone tell me how to approach this problem. I'm really clueless. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post whatever code you have written so far and indicate where you're stuck - then people here can help you to make progress.

Comment: Do you know about the malloc() and free() Function at all?

Comment: I want to get an approach. I really have no idea.

Comment: You are essentially asked to implement a heap, which is typically implemented as a linked list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - here is a starting point - the implementation of the actual `MyMalloc`/`MyFree` functions is left for you to do...

**File: mymalloc.h**

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void * MyMalloc(size_t size);
void MyFree(void * ptr);
```

**File: mymalloc.c**

```
#include "mymalloc.h"

#define POOL_SIZE 20000

static char pool[POOL_SIZE];

void * MyMalloc(size_t size)
{
     // TBD
}

void MyFree(void * ptr)
{
     // TBD
}
```

Note that you're probably going to need a suitable data structure to manage your allocations within the memory pool - typically one or more linked lists are used for this, but there are alternatives.